# How to check if there is more than one environment variable set for running Python scripts in PATH

Tags: python, django, windows, cmd

I am learning Django and in Command Prompt I have already installed Django, then when I check `django-admin --version` it says `'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Because of this I tried to install Django 3 times again but it still output the same.

**What is the cause of this problem?**

To test is my Django is working or not I have also tried to `import django` in my python interpreter. I have 2 python versions in my computer the first one is 3.8 and the second one is 3.8.6 ,which the CMD tells me to download. When I tried to `import django` in python3.8 it output `No module named 'django'`, when I tried to `import django` in python3.8.6 it worked !! I hope my python 3.8 work because my Pycharm is using that.

Comment: I have found that the most reliable method is to use `venv` and not put any `python.exe` into the PATH variable. Create a `venv` and activate it. Install Django and any other needed packages. The activate.bat script will set the environment variables needed, including PATH. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the python version set for the virtual environment. When creating a virtual environment specify the python version or it will use a default one which may not be the desired one:

```
whereis python
```

This would return a result similar to:

python: /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

And I create the virt env with this:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 djangoTut
```

There are other ways to create virt env. You could also use virtualenvwrapper

Comment: In `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 djangoTut` what is /usr/bin/, python3.6 is my python version right ? what is djangoTut ? So I have to write this in command prompt right ? 

Comment: @Themaster, don't worry about the answer above, it appears to have been written by someone who has not noticed that you used the [[tag:cmd]] tag. This means that they've formulated a response based upon an incorrect assumption that you're running a Unix system, and not a Windows one.

Comment: Yes, this would work on Unix system. You should check for similar to "virtualenv" command. In my case "djangoTut" is the name of the environment which would be created and you can name it as you need to.